# Chrome extension proxy settings clear with no permittion

Tags: google-chrome-extension, proxy, permissions

I am accidentally load wrong extension with proxy permission that set proxy settings by
chrome.proxy.settings.set, then i upload right version without proxy permission in  manifest.

But after update to right version current users still have proxy settings, and now i have not permission to fix that, and can't add new because of showing alert in chrome.

So, can i now clear proxy setting for my extension if i haven't proxy permission in manifest?

Thank you!

Comment: As mentioned [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/proxy), 

> you must declare the "proxy" permission in the [extension manifest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest) to use the proxy settings API.

 So I think it's a must that you have to include it in your manifest.

Comment: Yes, but if do that - on update extension will blocked by Chrome until person will not check 'ok', so i think, does that possible to just turn off proxy without that.